# 1с платформа: сравнение с текущей датой

Tags: 1с

Есть реквизит в документе "ДатаДоставки". Его пользователь заполняет сам. 
Как поставить запрет выбора даты раньше чем текущая дата?

Пыталась сравнить с текущей датой c выводом ошибки, но у меня код тоже не работает:

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ДатаПриИзменении(Элемент)
 Дата = Элементы.ДатаДоставки.ТекущиеДанные;
 Если Дата().Сравнить(ТекущаяДата()) = -1 Тогда
 Сообщить ("Ввод раньше текущей даты запрещен!");
 КонецЕсли

КонецПроцедуры
```

Comment: Обратите внимание, что пользователь вероятно может перевести локальное время на компе и внести данные с любой датой.

Comment: Да, вероятность есть.... тогда мне надо будет попробовать сравнивать с текущей датой сервера, попробую предложенный код на сервере

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно Вы неверно запрашиваете значение даты из формы. Вот так у меня работает:

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ДатаПриИзменении(Элемент)
   ДатаДоставки = Объект.ДатаДоставки;
   Если НачалоДня(ДатаДоставки) <  НачалоДня(ТекущаяДата()) Тогда
     Сообщить ("Ввод раньше текущей даты запрещен!");
   КонецЕсли;
КонецПроцедуры
```

Если Вам нужно, чтобы выводилось не только предупреждение, но запрещалось сохранять документ, то необходимо вставить эту проверку в процедуру `ПередЗаписью`:

```
Процедура ПередЗаписью(Отказ, РежимЗаписи, РежимПроведения)
    Если НачалоДня(ДатаДоставки) <  НачалоДня(ТекущаяДата()) Тогда
      Сообщить ("Ввод раньше текущей даты запрещен!");
      Отказ = Истина;
    КонецЕсли;
КонецПроцедуры
```

Comment: спасибо! Смогу попробовать применить только через несколько часов. Предварительно отмечу как отвеченный. 
А можете подсказать, как сделать, когда пользователь выбирает дату, сделать даты ранее текущей не активными? Это возможно?

Comment: Да, теперь заработало))))))

Answer (score -1):

```
Если Дата() <  ТекущаяДата() Тогда
 Сообщить ("Ввод раньше текущей даты запрещен!");
КонецЕсли;
```